# /bin/sh: line 62: to: command not found

Tags: python, json, shell, hadoop, subprocess

I have a python code in which I am calling a shell command. The part of the code where I did the shell command is:

```
try:
    def parse(text_list):
        text = '\n'.join(text_list)
        cwd = os.getcwd()
        os.chdir("/var/www/html/alenza/hdfs/user/alenza/sree_account/sree_project/src/core/data_analysis/syntaxnet/models/syntaxnet")
        synnet_output = subprocess.check_output(["echo '%s' | syntaxnet/demo.sh 2>/dev/null"%text], shell = True)
        os.chdir(cwd)
        return synnet_output
except Exception as e:
    sys.stdout.write(str(e))
```

Now, when i run this code on a local file with some sample input (I did `cat /home/sree/example.json | python parse.py`) it works fine and I get the required output. But I am trying to run the code with an input on my HDFS (the same `cat` command but input file path is from HDFS) which contains exactly the same type of json entries and it fails with an error:

```
/bin/sh: line 62: to: command not found
list index out of range
```

I read similar questions on Stack Overflow and the solution was to include a Shebang line for the shell script that is being called. I do have the shebang line `#!/usr/bin/bash` in `demo.sh` script.

Also, `which bash` gives `/usr/bin/bash`.

Someone please elaborate.

Comment: Looks like your question doesn't include the code you actually need help with. See if you can pare this down to a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You rarely, if ever, want to combine passing a list argument with `shell=True`. Just pass the string:

```
synnet_output = subprocess.check_output("echo '%s' | syntaxnet/demo.sh 2>/dev/null"%(text,), shell=True)
```

However, you don't really need a shell pipeline here.

```
from subprocess import check_output
from StringIO import StringIO  # from io import StringIO in Python 3
synnet_output = check_output(["syntaxnet/demo.sh"],
                             stdin=StringIO(text),
                             stderr=os.devnull)
```

Comment: I still get the same error for solution 1. It runs well with the file on my home directory but fails with input on HDFS. 

For the second one, I get an error: `StringIO instance has no attribute 'fileno'`

Comment: There are a couple of issues here. First, are you sure that `demo.sh` can read from standard input? Second, HDFS isn't a regular file system, and requires using special tools to interact with its contents.

Comment: I am sure `demo.sh` can read from standard input. Because the exact same code works for an input file in my home directory which contains the first 4 entries from the file on HDFS. I am assuming there is some data in the file on HDFS that is confusing `demo.sh`. Will update soon. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem with some special characters appearing in the text string that i was inputting to `demo.sh`. I solved this by storing `text` into a temporary file and sending the contents of that file to `demo.sh`.

That is:

```
try:
    def parse(text_list):
        text = '\n'.join(text_list)
        cwd = os.getcwd()
        with open('/tmp/data', 'w') as f:
            f.write(text)
        os.chdir("/var/www/html/alenza/hdfs/user/alenza/sree_account/sree_project/src/core/data_analysis/syntaxnet/models/syntaxnet")
        synnet_output = subprocess.check_output(["cat /tmp/data | syntaxnet/demo.sh 2>/dev/null"%text], shell = True)
        os.chdir(cwd)
        return synnet_output
except Exception as e:
    sys.stdout.write(str(e))
```